# Test `window.location.href` in Angular 4 Unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test a method in Angular4 which depends on `window.location.href`

My Method is as:

```
navigatePage(code: string) {
   const codeURL= (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementsByClassName('urlvalue')[0])
                        .value;
   window.location.href = codeURL;
}
```

To Test this method, i have written code as follows:

```
describe('navigate to url', () => {
    it('should call click', () => {
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        component.navigatePage(data.results[0].code);
      });
    });
});
```

When i check in test-coverage report then i see below line as not covered.

```
window.location.href = codeURL
```

Please assist.

Comment: Try: `fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(window.location.href).toContain(CallBack);`

Comment: what is this callback here

Comment: Your excepted result.

Comment: how can i mock codeURL?

Comment: You nt have to if "urlvalue" is set in your html.

Comment: .toContain("") This will give a fail with the expected result.

Comment: `loadNextPage(event) {
        this.actionService.actions.next(new LoadMoreAction(this.type));
        const target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
        const elemOffset = target.offsetTop;
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, elemOffset);
        }, 100);
    }` Any Idea how can i test this.. I am getting error at offsetTop of undefined

Comment: Please post an answer so that i can accept it

Comment: I can't answer it cause I can't see your the rest code.

Comment: But even after this `expect(window.location.href).toContain(CallBack);` it still shows uncovered